# How to create a utility type that finds out the depth of an object

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Can we create a type that finds out the depth of an object type?

For example,

```
type T = Depth<{a: string, b: { c: number, d: { z: boolean } }}>;
//   ^ T is 3

type T = Depth<{}>;
//   ^ T is 0

type T = Depth<'some random'>;
//   ^ T is 0
```

We suppose that all types inside (leaves) are only primitive types.

Comment: Would an empty object have a depth of `0`?

Comment: I'm going to need some edge cases from you; these kind of deep recursive type utilities usually have all kinds of weird behavior.  For example, maybe [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wjQn2W) meets your needs?  Please test it against other types you care about and let me know if you want me to write up an answer.  If it fails for some type you care about, please [edit] the question to show what you expect to see in these cases.  And mention me with @jcalz so I am notified.

Comment: @jcalz yes it works thank you so much (it's enough) you can add it as an answer or i add it if you want

Comment: I will write up an answer when I get a chance but it is now my bed time so probably not for a number of hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deeply nested recursive type functions like this tend to have strange side effects and edge cases.  I'm not going to worry about these too much, because the question doesn't ask about them.  But if someone writes `interface Foo {x: Foo}` and then `type Help = Depth<Foo>` I hope they don't complain to me about it.  Here goes:

---

TypeScript doesn't really let you do direct mathematics with numeric [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types), so there's no simple way to do `M + N` or `M < N` at the type level.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#26382](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26382) for a feature request for this.

Instead you can manipulate [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) to grow/shrink/compare tuples, and then use their strongly-typed `"length"` properties to get the corresponding numeric literal.  So while I can't write `M + N` where `M` and `N` are numeric literal types, I *can* write `[...M, ...N]` where `M` and `N` are tuple types, and then `[...M, ...N]['length']` will be the sum of `M['length']` and `N['length']`.

That means in the following approach we will be carrying around tuple types in places you might not expect them.  Here goes:

```
type Depth<T, A extends any[] = []> =
    T extends object ?
    T extends readonly any[] ? Max<0 | Depth<T[number], [any, ...A]>> :
    Max<0 | { [K in keyof T]: Depth<T[K], [any, ...A]> }[keyof T]> :
    A['length']
```

The basic idea is that `Depth<T, A>` computes the depth of type `T`, while carrying around a "current depth" tuple `A`, that starts out as zero (the empty tuple `[]`).  If `T` is not an `object` type, then we just return the current depth `A['length']`.  Otherwise, if `T` is an array type, we want to find the maximum depth of each one of the properties and add one to it (adding one here looks like `[any, ...A]` where `A` is the tuple we want to add to).

There are a few complications... first, we need to special-case array types to avoid hitting recursion depth limits if `T` contains arrays anywhere.  So instead of iterating over `keyof T` for arrays, we just add one to the depth of `T[number]`, which is the element type of the array.  Second, we want to include `0` in the list of things to get the maximum of, in case we iterate over an object with no properties.  Third, there's no built in `Max` type function; we have to define it:

```
type Max<N> = Exclude<N, LessThan<N>>
```

So the `Max<N>` of a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of numeric literal types `N` is just what you get if you [`Exclude`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion) from `N` all the numbers less than all the elements of `N`.  So if `N` is `2 | 4 | 6` and all the numbers less than `N` are `0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5`, then excluding the latter from the former is `6`.  That's great but we have no definition of `LessThan`.  Here we go:

```
type LessThan<N, A extends number[] = []> =
    N extends A['length'] ? A[number] : LessThan<N, [A['length'], ...A]>;
```

This is a [tail recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#tail-recursion-elimination-on-conditional-types) which again uses variadic tuples to build up an array of numbers less than `N`.  Essentially it keeps adding numbers to `A` until `A` has a length `N`.  So `LessThan<3>` evaluates to `LessThan<3, [0]>` and to `LessThan<3, [0, 1]>` and to `LessThan<3, [0, 1, 2]>` at which point the length is `3` and then we get `0 | 1 | 2`.  And since this [distributes across unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) then `LessThan<2 | 4>` ends up becoming `(0 | 1) | (0 | 1 | 2 | 3)` which is `0 | 1 | 2 | 3`.  You can see how `LessThan<N>` where `N` is a union ends up calculating something like one less than  the maximum of `N`.

---

Okay, so there we go; let's test it:

```
type T1 = Depth<{ a: string, b: { c: number, d: { z: boolean } } }>;
// type T1 = 3

type T2 = Depth<{}>;
// type T2 = 0 

type T3 = Depth<'some random'>;
//  type T3 = 0
```

Looks good, at least for the examples in the question.  As I said, I'm *sure* there are edge cases where someone would be unhappy with the outcome.  And as I said, I can't worry about them because I'd be spending forever fine-tuning this thing.  So be careful and good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9&noErrorTruncation=true&ts=4.7.4#code/FAguE8AcFMAIBloGckBUAWBDAdgHgHIA0sAgrNAB6jTYAmSs2ArgLYBG0ATgNoC6sAXlh8AfIOCxJsfOSo16pbgHIANjQDmodEv4B+Rc3Zd+ALgTI0WPEWElla7Ju29iAOncleIgNxgocAFlMCgIxIQBRCgBjFSZaaAJiRBQMHFCRPxhYABFoSC1cVGIySmo6BhxwPkFhL3EpWFRZMoUAezYAK2go0FhdCSkm0vkGTmhMWlbsFXBYSur9IJCABlgAHxy8gtRuQw5OF2FKtw8vMRMBySXcVY2Ab2EAaVgAS2xYAGtocFaAM0beGZcvl0IVuI9DtxjrB3K5PGIAL7cL4-f6oOoXBp2VQaLQ6EDACBZVAARhqwIKD0wZiQoE4b3UxDYZgeUTMey4xFoLNgAC8zGxWq01DhYAixWKfMAAPTS2BEuCkmoAZkyioATOStqC7gipbL5f5GpqhKs1Y1lVqQbglEhWiw4JwcJMWEp9XLDcTLabYEA)